# how to retrieve data in current URL and send it to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My current url is `http://webly.com/mysite.php?cat=woman`

what is the best way to get "cat" from current url automatically and send it to another page  every time the page is loaded

I want to get in `http://webly.com/dolor/data.php` => sex = $_GET['cat']

Answer (score 1):

If you have jquery on your page, then you should do this -

```
$.get("http://webly.com/dolor/data.php" + window.location.search);
```

window.location.search will give you the entire search string.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need Ajax.

If you want to do it with jQuery, take a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Please be more specific about what you tried and what you need and I'll gladly expand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the document ready give an ajax call to the data.php with the url data as parameter.